# Prove convegent sequences space has the same dimensionality as bounded sequences and series converging to $0$ spaces.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a field ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and let $$c(K)=\{x:\mathbb{N}\mapsto K : \lim{x_n}\text{ exists}\},$$
be the vector space of converging sequences and
$$c_0(K)=\{x:\mathbb{N}\mapsto K : \lim{x_n}=0\},$$
the subspace of sequences converging to zero.

I am to prove that $\dim_k{c}=\dim_k{c_0}=\dim_k{{\ell}_{\infty}}$. Where $\ell_\infty$ is the space of all bounded sequences.

I know from a previously solved problem that the dimensionality of any two Hamel bases in a space is the same, so I imagine that I'll be done with the proof by exhibiting a basis for each space of interest, and two bijective functions linking them.

I'm stumped as to where to direct the attack to. I was given the following hint: *Consider $(1,r,r^2,\dots)$ for $0<r<1$.* Although I don't really know how to use it.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to actually construct the Hamel bases.  I think you are supposed to use the Schröder-Bernstein Theorem.  Use that the map $(x_n) \mapsto (r^{-n} x_n)$ defines an injection from $\ell_\infty$ to $c_0$.

Comment: That there is an injection from $\ell_\infty \mapsto c_o$, along with CSB proves that all three spaces have the same cardinality. That they have the same dimension has to be proven through bases (as far as I know). Given a basis $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha}$ for $\ell_\infty$, appying the map stated above *should* yield a basis for $c_0$, then both spaces would have the same dimension.

Comment: Not quite.  Applying the map to $(x_\alpha)$ will give a linearly independent subset of $c_0$.  Then extend it to a basis of $c_0$.

Comment: In other words, there is an injection from any Hamel basis of $\ell_\infty$ to a Hamel basis of $c_0$.  This gives you one half of what you need to use Schroeder-Bernstein.  The other half is easier.